# OpenTelemetry OLTP Java server example

Tags: java, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

I am looking for a java server example that can be used to ingest Metrics based on OpenTelemetry OLTP (Something prometheus endpoint to receive metrics).

I am trying to apply some server side transformation for collected telemetry metrics before pushing them to sink.

Gone through telegraph sidecar [processor plugin samples](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/PROCESSORS.md) but that doesn't suites our design and is required to do transformation.

I tried looking into opentelemetry java examples but they primarily are based on client side exporters [OpenTelemetry OLTP exporter example](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-examples/tree/main/otlp/docker) but I am looking for server side code example that handles those events (primarily collector or something similar to prometheus server to which any agent publishes data to).

Getting any curl / some simple test / Standalone code is bonus.

Comment: I am not sure what's is not clear. Looking for a java server reference that is based on OLTP protocol and processes metrics published in prometheus format? Person who marked this as closed should have asked for details if something not clear instead of marking this as closed.